# AWS Glue throws AWSBadRequestException when loading DynamicFrame from s3 with local Glue docker

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have been using AWS Glue 4.0 docker image to locally develop and test ETL jobs. This worked perfectly for DynamoDB exports, but now I have been having troubles with loading files from S3.

I have set of files exported from AWS CloudWatch that I wanted to load into data lake. I created following DynamicFrame configuration

```
df_raw = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            f"s3://{audit_logs_source_bucket}/exports/aws-cloudwatch/logs/audit/access-logs/api/apigw/",
        ],
        "recurse": True,
        "exclusions": json.dumps([
            "aws-logs-write-test",
        ]),
    },
    format="grokLog",
    format_options={
        "logFormat": r"%{NOTSPACE:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}",
    },
    transformation_ctx="load_new_logs",
)
```

but when I execute it (I have Administrator access permission set on training account) then I get following exception:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.getDynamicFrame.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: getFileStatus on s3://bucket-operators-data-export-eu-west-1-rnd/exports/aws-cloudwatch/logs/audit/access-logs/api/apigw: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request
```

When I run the same code in AWS Glue Interractive Session then it works properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Py4JJavaError with AWSBadRequestException you're encountering when trying to access an S3 bucket using PySpark or AWS Glue indicates a problem with the request made to AWS S3. This error can be caused by several issues, including incorrect S3 endpoint configuration, using an unsupported authentication API version, or issues with the bucket name or path. You may have IAM administrative permissions, but you may be restricted to reach the S3. 

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com") # Adjust the endpoint based on your bucket's region